# Are all the library functions linked by default

Tags: linker

I knew that header files contain **declarations** of functions and variables which help during compilation time whether the entered parameters are valid or not.

**Are all the library functions linked by default?**

```
//#include<stdio.h>
//#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");

    double d;
    d=sqrt(64);
    printf("%lf",d);    

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and produces few warnings as expected

Output

```
Hello
8.000000
```

It works!
**Are all the library functions linked by default?**

Comment: `printf()` is part of the standard libc, which is linked by default, so the linker will find its entry point. But for `sqrt()` you should specify `-lm`, so I'm waiting for others to answer as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most linkers from C toolchain link stdlib by default unless you disable this behaviour with a flag for example `-nodefaultlibs` or `-nostdlibs` in `gcc`.

> Are all the library functions linked by default?

Not all, but standard library functions are usually linked by default by linkers.

Comment: What about math? I thought `sqrt()` needed `-lm`.

Comment: C linkers don't include it by default. One need to explicitly provide it. (Interestingly on a different line libstd++ needs libm so in C++ it is default)

Comment: Linkers do *not* add any files or libraries by default, *compiler drivers* do. `gcc` is not a linker.

Comment: @EmployedRussian You are right. I am talking about the toolchain here. They may have something similar to `-lc` in linker invocation as default to avoid repetition of the widely used setting.